# Programa incluye extension en nombre al mover archivos

Tags: java

Tengo un programa en Java donde al copiar un grupo de archivos, a la hora de copiarlos, los copio de la siguiente manera, este es el codigo del método donde los copia:

```
public static void copyFiles(String src, String dst)
{
    int x = 0;
    eFilex = new File(src);
    listOfFiles = eFilex.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
        {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
            {
                fileName = listOfFiles[i].getName();//Aqui es donde obtiene el nombre
                if (fileName.endsWith(".pdf") || fileName.endsWith(".PDF"))//Evalua que sea tipo PDF
                {
                    try {
                            srcPth = Paths.get(src, fileName); 
                            eNumber = getNumber(fileName);
                            fDirectory = NewFolderNumber(dst, eNumber);
                            dstPth = Paths.get(fDirectory, fileName);
                            eFilex = new File(fDirectory, fileName);
                            if(!eFilex.exists())
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    Files.copy(srcPth, dstPth, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
                                    System.out.println("Archivo organizado");
                                    x++;
                                }
                                catch (Exception e) 
                                {
                                   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.out.println("Ya existe el archivo..");
                            }
                        } 
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    System.out.println("Archivos copiados: " + x);
}
```

En las variables que recibe el método solo van dos direcciones que tengo en un propertie.
El problema es que a la hora de que los copia en la nueva carpeta, pone el nombre con la extension, de llamarse "S00A-205420-0000", ahora se llama "S00A-205420-0000.pdf"
¿Que es lo que causa eso?

Comment: No entiendo bien el problema. ¿Quieres decir que el archivo de origen se llama `S00A-algo`, sin extensión, y al copiarlo a la nueva ubicación se llama `S00A-algo.pdf`? De ser así, yo realizaría un debug para ver cómo se crea el valor de `dstPth` y observar en qué punto se agrega esa extensión.

Comment: Así es, es el unico detalle, cuando obtengo el nombre del archivo, lo trae con todo y extension, ya que después tengo que verificar que sea PDF. La variable `dstPth` es toda la dirección nueva a la que se mueve el documento, ya había intentado con la función `renameTo`, y esta no hacia eso, pero los movia, yo necesitaba que los copiara.

Comment: Por favor edita la publicación y agrega el código relevante para evaluar el proceso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código lo que realiza es buscar los archivos cuyo nombre tenga al terminar ".pdf":

```
 if (fileName.endsWith(".pdf") || fileName.endsWith(".PDF"))//Evalua que sea tipo PDF
```

en base a esto estas copiando los archivos con extensión `.pdf`!

por cierto puedes simplificar lo anterior con:

```
if (fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf"))//Evalua que sea tipo PDF
```

Deseas  detectar los archivos que terminen con `.pdf` y copiarlos sin extensión?

puedes usar este método para eliminar la extensión de los nombres:

```
 static String eliminaExtension (String str) {
        if (str == null) return null;
        int pos = str.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (pos == -1) return str;
        return str.substring(0, pos);
    }
```

por ejemplo, el método anteriormente mencionado lo usarias en la línea:

```
Files.copy(srcPth, eliminaExtension(dstPth), StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
```

Comment: Otra improvisación al código es mover todas las validaciones de archivo a un `FileFilter` que será el argumento de `eFilex.listFiles()`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza muy buen punto para Kevin M, lo tomé en cuenta. :)

Comment: Fijate que utilice ese metodo en donde asigno el directorio destino: `dstPth = Paths.get(fDirectory, deleteExtension(fileName));` pero cuando los mueve, prácticamente les quita el formato pdf. Igual no es que cause tanto problema, pero se me hacia raro que al copiar cambiara el nombre y no cuando se mueven.

Answer (score 0):

Mira este metodo se puede utilizar de JAVA 7 para arriba
le podrias poner validaciones al destino para que no lo sobreescriba pero te funcionara sin afectar la extension

```
 public synchronized static void copyFile(String origen, String destino) throws IOException {
       // System.out.println(origen);
      //  System.out.println(destino);
        Path FROM = Paths.get(origen);
        Path TO = Paths.get(destino);
        //sobreescribir el fichero de destino, si existe, y copiar
        // los atributos, incluyendo los permisos rwx
        CopyOption[] options = new CopyOption[]{
            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
            StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES
        };
        Files.copy(FROM, TO, options);



    }
```